# Regex, single quote or double quote

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
preg_replace(
    '/\["'.$key.'"\] = (.+?);/is', '["'.$key.'"] = '.$newValue.';',
    $contents);
```

It writes an array value in a config file.  I need to allow single or double quotes around the array key and I'm not sure how to do that.  I didn't write this regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the "find" regex to match both types of quotes:

```
'/\[[\'"]'.$key.'[\'"]\] = (.+?);/is'
```

This will even match:

```
["MegaKey'] = UberValue;
```

And if I were you, I'd put this configuration file on the list of things to rewrite without regexes.

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to handle multiple quoting styles is to spell them out: `/'a'|"a"/`, duplicating what is inside the quotes, though it may very well be slightly different (such as to disallow an unescaped single quote within a single-quoted string.

```
'/\[("'.$key.'"|\''.$key.'\')\] = (.+?);/is'
```

You can also, sometimes, use a back reference:

```
'/\[([\'"])'.$key.'\\1\] = (.+?);/is'
```

Comment: +1 nice options; I do think the back reference needs a double escape like `\\1`

Comment: Thanks, been using raw string literals too much lately. :)

Comment: +1 the backref is the best solution here, less likely to accept nonsense `['asdf"]`.  \\1 would be necessary if the regex was in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do back-referencing to match the correct set of quotes used (opened with double, closed with double)

```
preg_replace(
    '/\[([\"\']+)'.$key.'\\1\]\s=\s(.+?);/is', '[\\1'.$key.'\\1] = '.$newValue.';',
    $contents);
```

`\\1` matches the first type of quote used

Comment: +1 is it intentional to match any number of quotes like `["'"key"'"]`

Comment: well, we can also match only one quote too using the `{1}`