# Regexp matching equal number of the same character on each side of a string

Tags: python, regex

How do you match only equal numbers of the same character (up to 3) on each side of a string in python?

For example, let's say I am trying to match equal signs

`=abc=` or `==abc==` or `===abc===`

but not

`=abc==` or `==abc=`

etc.

I figured out how to do each individual case, but can't seem to get all of them.

`(={1}(?=abc={1}))abc(={1})`

as `|` of the same character

`((={1}(?=abc={1}))|(={2}(?=abc={2})))abc(={1}|={2})`

doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
^(=+)abc\1$
```

Edit:

If you are talking about only max three `=`

```
^(={1,3})abc\1$
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a regular language. However, you can do it with backreferences:

```
(=+)[^=]+\1
```

Answer (score 0):

consider that sample is a single string, here's a non-regex approach (out of many others)

```
>>> string="===abc==="
>>> string.replace("abc"," ").split(" ")
['===', '===']
>>> a,b = string.replace("abc"," ").split(" ")
>>> if a == b:
...   print "ok"
...
ok
```

You said you want to match equal characters on each side, so regardless of what characters, you just need to check `a` and `b` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use a back reference.  Check this post for an example:

[Regex, single quote or double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779010/regex-single-quote-or-double-quote)